# Facebook Graph API Explorer not listing tagged photos uploaded by others

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook photos that others upload and tag me in are no longer being listed by Graph API Explorer. Previously, my photos were accessible, e.g., using

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos%2F&version=v2.12

But, photos I'm tagged in, but didn't upload, are no longer being listed. How can I access these photos using Facebook's Graph API Explorer?

Comment: I am still seeing mine which I didn't upload. Possibly some profile privacy changes in the user that may have changed for you?

Comment: I'll double check, but I'm pretty certain that no profile changes have been made to the accounts of the tagger/me...

Comment: On top right option, which application do you select? "Graph API explorer" Application or yours? If it is yours, it may be required to submit a login review for your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#4-4-2018  and  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: @JannesBotis I'm testing using the Graph API explorer application, not my own.

Comment: Try "me/friends", are the friends that tagged you in their photos in that list? Also try "me/feed" to see if you get a warning. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#tagged-users-4-4

Comment: @JannesBotis The friend that tagged me isn't listed in "me/friends." The tags are listed in "me/feed." The former provides a debug message ("Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app."), the latter provides no debug message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that facebook has tighten up its graph api requirements, causing  [breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#tagged-users-4-4):

> Apps can no longer get photo...objects for non-app Users who have been tagged by an app User

The wording doesn't precisely capture your scenario -- *apps can no longer get photo objects* uploaded by *non-app Users* that tagged *an app user* (hence, you cannot access all tags) -- but that's probably a wording issue by facebook.

The issue is that your friends that tagged you in their photos are **non-app users**. They should install the same app and give it access to the following permissions:

- user_friends
- user_photos

You need to make sure that you give the app those permission too.

You can see which friends have installed the app by using **[me/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.12)**, it will list only friends who have installed the app.

In your case, since you are testing with "Graph API explorer application" just point a friend to the **Graph API Explorer** and ask them to give it the above permissions. After that, you should be able to get **photos that you are tagged** from this user.

Comment: My edit corrects the original answer to provide a working solution and elaborates on the _breaking changes_.